# Why am i getting garbage values as my output using this android-lockpattern library?

Tags: java, android, android-library

I am using the android lock pattern library for a project of mine when I print the output pattern in a toast I get all garbage values like [C245faa3a8

I got the library and the code from https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/

here is my code.

```
public class PatternTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // This is your preferred flag

        Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN,
                null, getBaseContext(), LockPatternActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CREATE_PATTERN);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        char[] pattern = null;
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CREATE_PATTERN: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                pattern = data
                        .getCharArrayExtra(LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PATTERN);

            }
            break;
        }// REQ_CREATE_PATTERN
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pattern.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm, how exactly do you expect to GetExtra if you never PutExtra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `new String(byte[])` instead of `toString()`:

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),new String(pattern),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: i tried that but i just get a huge string of values.when i tried the demo app the result had come nicely.for eg '1-2-3-6' if i would chose point 1,2,3 and 6

Comment: can you provide me with a link to demo app?

Comment: heres the link [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.demo)

Comment: my answer should work. just tested with Log.d("DEBUG", new String(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'})); - I get the "abc" String.